# Python inheritance child class raising error

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class student():
    def __init__(self,fname,lname):
        self.name = fname
        self.lastname = lname
    def printthis(self):
        print(self.name,self.lastname)


class person(student):
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,age):
        student. __init__ (fname, lname)
        self.umar = age
    def wlcm(self):
        print(self.name,self.lastname,self.umar)
e = student("HARJOT", "GILL", 20)
e.wlcm()
```

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong here it gives me an error
(TypeError: student.**init**() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given)
I am unable to figure out. the child class is raising the problem.

Comment: The `__init__()` method of the `student` class only takes two arguments (`self` is special and it doesn't count).  But you're passing three arguments `student("HARJOT", "GILL", 20)`

Comment: _the child class is raising the problem_ No, it isn't the child class.  The child class is `person`, but you're declaring an object of type `student`.

Comment: Did you mean to do: e=person("hariot", "gill", 20) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

When you want to initialize child class using parent's **init**,
you should call -> super().**init**(params)

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.name = fname
        self.lastname = lname

    def pprint(self):
        print(self.name, self.lastname)

class person(student):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, age):
        super().__init__(fname, lname)
        self.umar = age

    def pprint(self):
        print(self.name, self.lastname, self.umar)

s = person('c', 'mor', 27)
s.pprint()
```

Comment: yes exactly but can't I initialize the properties in child class like this

Comment: student.__init__ (fname,lname)

Comment: I just figured it out now, my mistake. Thanks for helping appreciate. I am so dumb.